# Huge sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, memory, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to iteratively construct a huge sparse matrix in numpy/scipy. The intitialization is done within  a loop:

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix, csr_matrix

def foo(*args):
    dim_x = 256*256*1024
    dim_y = 128*128*512
    matrix = dok_matrix((dim_x, dim_y))    

    for i in range(dim_x):
        # compute stuff in order to get j
        matrix[i, j] = 1.
    return matrix.tocsr()
```

Then i need to convert it to a csr_matrix, because of further computations like:

```
matrix = foo(...)
result = matrix.T.dot(x)
```

At the beginning this was working fine. But my matrices are getting bigger and bigger and my computer starts to crash. Is there a more elegant way in storing the matrix?

Basically i have the following requirements:

- The matrix needs to store float values form 0. to 1.
- I need to compute the transpose of the matrix
- I need to compute the dot product with a x_dimensional vector
- The matrix dimensions can be around 1*10^9 x 1*10^8

My ram-storage is exceeding. I was reading several posts on stack overflow and the rest of the internet ;) I found PyTables, which isn't really made for matrix computations... etc.. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think this may be more of a mathmatical / numerical analysis question :) In my Num.Anal. course, the only way to do a matrix of that size is to make it tridiagonal.

Comment: Also, I know you are asking for numpy, but I have a somewhat finished library for python. [It's on github](https://github.com/Twoody/Lin_Alg_py)

Comment: When you asked this question, it appeared you wanted to store floats, but you accepted an answer that suggested ints. I'm just curious - what did I miss here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may have hit the limits of what Python can do for you, or you may be able to do a little more. Try setting a datatype of `np.float32`, if you're on a 64 bit machine, this reduced precision may reduce your memory consumption. `np.float16` may help you on memory even further, but your calculations may slow down (I've seen examples where processing may take 10x the amount of time):

```
    matrix = dok_matrix((dim_x, dim_y), dtype=np.float32)
```

or possibly much slower, but even less memory consumption:

```
    matrix = dok_matrix((dim_x, dim_y), dtype=np.float16)
```

---

Another option: buy more system memory.

---

Finally, if you can avoid creating your matrix with `dok_matrix`, and can create it instead with `csr_matrix` (I don't know if this is possible for your calculations) you may save a little overhead on the dict that `dok_matrix` uses.

Answer (score 2):

For your case I would recommend using the data type `np.int8` (or `np.uint8`) which require only one byte per element:

```
matrix = dok_matrix((dim_x, dim_y), dtype=np.int8)
```

Directly constructing the `csr_matrix` will also allow you to go further with the maximum matrix size:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def foo(*args):
    dim_x = 256*256*1024
    dim_y = 128*128*512
    row = []
    col = []

    for i in range(dim_x):
        # compute stuff in order to get j
        row.append(i)
        col.append(j)
    data = np.ones_like(row, dtype=np.int8)

    return csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(dim_x, dim_y), dtype=np.int8)
```